# python class call super's method instead of inherited

Tags: python, class, inheritance, super, self

I have the following problem

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = "<I am window class>"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def createObject(self):
        print(self.window)  # it works here
        self.c = C()

    def drawRect(self):
        print(self.window)  # does not work when called from class C

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        super().drawRect()

app = B()
app.createObject()
```

I have figured that, when I call the `super().drawRect()` function in class C
it sends the `<__main__.C object at 0x0000023D99FA6748>` as self.

How can I make class C, in function draw() send `<__main__.B object at 0x0000017A2BA95358>` in the `super().drawRect()`

I am asking because in the non-simplified code when I call the function from the B class itself, it prints the self.window, but when called from the C class it prints None

how can this be fixed?
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `B` object when you create an instance of `C`, there is only a `C` instance that happens to inherit from `B`.

So the answer to your question:

> How can I make class C, in function `draw()` send `<__main__.B object at 0x0000017A2BA95358>` in the `super().drawRect()`

Is: You can't.

You could create a new `B` object (but that would defy the purpose of inheritance) alongside your `C` object.

But it seems more reasonable that you should just call `super().__init__` in `C.__init__`:

```
class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        super().drawRect()
```

It would be weird not to do that anyway. Because inheritance sort of implies that you **extend** rather than **override completely**.

But given the fact that you do `self.c = C()` in your `B.createObject` method and `C` inherits from `B` you should probably figure out another way (e.g. [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)) instead of inheritance:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = "<I am window class>"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def createObject(self):
        print(self.window)  # it works here
        self.c = C(self)

    def drawRect(self):
        print(self.window)  # does not work when called from class C

class C(object):   # don't inherit from B
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        self.obj.drawRect()

app = B()
app.createObject()
```

However this will create a reference cycle because you store the `C` instance as attribute of your `B` instance and the `B` instance as attribute of your `C` instance. It's also possible that you simplified the code too much, maybe the real code prevents composition in some way. However given the current code it seems like inheriting from `B` is a bad idea for your class `C` given that it overrides `B`s behavior completely and doesn't use any of it's attributes (which it can't anyway because you overrode the methods).

Answer (score 0):

you need to call to

```
super().__init__()
```

in class C constructor

Charlie